# "single file" git repository format?

Tags: git

### Summary

Does git natively support local repositories stored inside single file?

---

### Motivation

I have many usecases, where I use git primarily for change-tracking on local files, which are synchronized over Dropbox/Spideroak and in some cases rsync between multiple machines. Many of these directories are small (1 to 10 files), while the `.git` directories contain approximately 40 files after garbage collection.

This results in major file clutter, as in many cases there are ten times more files in the `.git` directory than there are versioned files, which slows down backups. For Dropbox/SpiderOak it introduces the risk of accidentally shutting down the client machine while only *some* of the repository files have been synchronized, thus putting an inconsistent repository on the other machines, which is significantly harder to resolve than accidentally working with an outdated version of the complete repository.

These problems would be avoided, if it were possible to store the local git repository in a single file instead of a large directory tree. I probably could easily solve this myself (using a `zip`/`unzip` wrapper around the `git` command), but I was wondering if there are more convenient / officially supported options (e.g. alternate file formats for the local repository).

Comment: Why are you distributing git over Dropbox? Git includes its own distribution protocols. Why not use one of these? That would be the "more convenient / officially supported" option.

Comment: Not really convenient for private files (Github is no option for these, and I don't want to maintain a server). Also, it would introduce push/pull into the workflow where right now the workflow is "leave office pc, continue on home pc" with no extra steps, as for unversioned files. It also wouldn't solve the file-clutter problem, but potentially make it worse.

Comment: You can also use Gitlab, they have unlimited private repositories for free

Comment: Very interesting question. I guess mounting some kind of read-writable archive file (an .iso, .zip etc) into your file system as the storage for the .git folder could work. Afterall, a git repo can be rebuilt from the .git folder alone.

Answer (score 6):

> store the local git repository in a single file instead of a large directory tree. ... officially supported options (e.g. alternate file formats for the local repository).

Sounds like [bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). It combines objects and references into single file, which can later be referred to as remote. It does not however contain config, hooks, and other settings.

Comment: Sadly not really a solution for my usecase, since it can't replace the `.git` directory: As far as I can tell it isn't possible to commit directly to a bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Fossil (https://fossil-scm.org/) is the way to go in this case. You have only one executable file and only one for each repository. You can update, copy, delete the file and all your opened repositories in other directories somewhere would get this changes if you run `fossil update` or using sync option.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks for pointing it out. Since it is also about resume building, however, I don't think I can apply it. Git + Github wins there, even if the repository format isn't a good match for the use-case.